# Implications of independence of several random variables

Tags: conditional-probability, independence, conditioning

Consider 4 real-valued random variables $X,Y,Z,V$ defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Assume that $X$ is independent of $Y,Z,V$, i.e. the probability distribution function of $X$ conditioned on $Y,Z,V$ is equivalent to the unconditional one $$
p_{X|Y,Z,V}(x)=p_X(x)
$$

Does this imply $X$ independent of $Y$, i.e. 
$$
p_{X|Y}(x)=p_X(x)
$$
?
If yes, could you provide a proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $X \perp (Y, Z, V)$. Claim: $X \perp Y$.

Proof sketch: for convenience I'll assume that all of these random variables have densities with respect to the Lebesgue measure so that I can just write $dx$ and whatnot. I'll denote these marginal densities by $f_X$ and etc. You'll probably want to make this more rigorous.

$$
f_{(X,Y)} = \int_{Z \times V}  f_{(X,Y,Z,V)} d z\times v = \int_{Z \times V}  f_X f_{(Y,Z,V)} d z\times v
$$

$$
= f_X \int_{Z \times V}  f_{(Y,Z,V)} d z\times v = f_X f_Y \ \ \ \ \square
$$

This might be another way although I'm not sure if I'm missing something here: let $g:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by $g((a, b, c)) = a$. Note that this function is measurable. We know for any two random elements $U$ and $W$ that $U \perp W \implies h_1(U) \perp h_2(W)$ for any measurable functions $h_1$ and $h_2$. This means that in your case $X \perp (Y, Z, V) \implies X \perp g((Y, Z, V)) = Y$.